# Create dynamic Type Java

Tags: java, abstract

explain my problem:

I have a super abstract class called First and then I have a lot of class that inherit from it. 
I want to build a method that I "say" to it "create a ArrayList  of one of the types that inherit from First class", but I'm not to able to find solution.
For example:

```
public abstract class First{

   public First(){
   }
}

public class FirstOne extends First{

   ...........
}

//It's a pseudo-code
public class MyProgramClass{

   public creatingMethod(TypeThatInheritFromFirstClass x ){
      return ArrayList<TypeThatInheritFromFirstClass>;
   }
}
```

I insert creatingMethod in program class,but it can be anywhere(I prefer in First class like static method, but it's an example)

Thank for your time

Comment: At run time, an `ArrayList` is an `ArrayList` is an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I want to automate a mechanism. I explain better: in the program I have this class that inherit from super abstract class and when I create they I call always "activate" and "position" method. automating this process with a few rows of code I create variuos type object. I do not know if I explained well

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [*type token*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html):

```
public class SomeGenerics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SubFirst1> list1 = creatingMethod(SubFirst1.class);
        List<SubFirst2> list2 = creatingMethod(SubFirst2.class);
    }
    public static <T extends First> List<T> creatingMethod(Class<T> type) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

class First {}
class SubFirst1 extends First {}
class SubFirst2 extends First {}
```

---

EDIT as per the comment:

As you already have the *type token*, you can use it for creating instances of that type. A little restriction is, that you must know what constructor to use. If they - for example - all have a parameterless constructor, you can create instances like that:

```
public static <T extends First> List<T> creatingMethod(Class<T> type) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(type.newInstance());
    return result;
}
```

If you have a constructor with parameters (again: all sub classes must have the same parameterized constructor), you must go a more difficult way. Example with a string parameter:

```
public static <T extends First> List<T> creatingMethod(Class<T> type, String param) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Constructor<T> constructor = type.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
    result.add(constructor.newInstance(param));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's similar to that I want, but there is a problem.In creatingMethod I must call constructor of the type in input and then add created object  in ArrayList

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand how I use the second example, I have four parameters in the constructor. How Do I it? Thank you again

Comment: @user3550545 Then simply pass four parameters to the method. It's the same as you would call a constructor.